# "reduce each zero distance" mapping

Tags: metric-spaces

The problem is:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $K:X\to X$ be a mapping such that $d(K(x),K(y))<d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$. Prove that $X$ has a unique fixed point. (Hint: assume that otherwise $\operatorname{glb}\{d(x,K(x)):x\in X\}$ is positive and achieved as a minimum. Then get a contradiction.)

The upper part of the hint has been done and what makes me stuck is deducing a contradiction from it. Lots of thanks to everyone who is willing to help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note d(K(x),K(y))<d(x,y) is definitely false when x=y.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove that by contradiction. Lets suppose that it doesn't have a fixed point, since X is compact we have then that the set

$$
C=\{d(x,K(x))|x \in X\}
$$

has a minimum $m > 0$.

With that lets consider the point $x_0$ such that $d(x_0,K(x_0)) =m$. Then we would have that if we consider $x = x_0$ and $y = K(x_0)$, which both belong to $X$,

$$
d(K(x_0), K(K(x0))) < d(x0, K(x_0)) = m
$$

Which is a contradiction since we said before that $m$ was the smallest number such that $d(x,K(x)) = m$ $\forall x \in X$.

Comment: "Proof": Noun - a logical demonstration that some statement is true. "Prove": Verb - to produce a proof.

Comment: Many thanks. Have a nice day